# Correctly address content of xlsx in js-xlsx and manipulate it

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx, js-xlsx

I want to export xlsx files using js-xlsx on my Node.JS server. I can read files and save them. But as i try to fill the Table with content it does not work.

I fill it using lines like these:

```
for (var i = 0; i < workbook.SheetNames.length; i++) {
    var sheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[i]];
    var studenten = stapel[workbook.SheetNames[i]];

    sheet["A1"] = {v: "This is a test!",t:"s"};

    workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[i]] = sheet;
}
```

, I tried using this notation for the cell address too

```
{c:0,r:0}
```

but as i export my file the tables are empty. Creating different worksheets works fine but i can't fill the tables with content. Could someone here enlighten me on how to correctly address the tables and manipulate their content?

Thanks in advance!

update:
even

```
function Workbook() {
    if (!(this instanceof Workbook)) return new Workbook();
    this.SheetNames = [];
    this.Sheets = {};
}

var workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.SheetNames.push("1");
workbook.Sheets[1] = {'A1': {v: "HI",t:"s"}};
```

doesn't work. I think I don't understand the API!

Comment: Used node-xlsx to get it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this today myself and took some time to find the reason. The solution is to set the "!ref" Value in a worksheet:

```
workbook.Sheets[1] = {'!ref': "A1", 'A1': {v: "HI",t:"s"}};
```

The "!ref" is used to define the area that contains data within the sheet.
This is from the official documentation:

> **sheet['!ref']**: A-1 based range representing the sheet range. Functions that work with sheets should use this parameter to determine the range. **Cells that are assigned outside of the range are not processed**. In particular, when writing a sheet by hand, cells outside of the range are not included